# Can Windows Server 2012 R2 be installed onto M.2 SSD drive?

Tags: boot, ssd, raid, windows-server-2012-r2, m.2

I'm about to build a server machine based on *XEON E-2246G* placed most probably into *ASUS WS C246 PRO* and I want to have a M.2 SSD drive as primary for the OS *Windows Server 2012 R2*. The M.2 SSD disk (*WD BLACK SSD NVMe 500GB PCIe SN750 (WDS500G3X0C)*) will be placed directly into M.2 slot on the motherboard.

Most probably I will need to have BIOS set to "RAID" mode in the storage section because I might need some HW RAID setup in the future.

Question:
Will it work without issues? (meaning installing the OS onto M.2 and booting it) - so far, I've never had this OS on M.2 so I would like to be sure...

Thanks!

Comment: M.2 SATA, M.2 PCIe, or NVMe?  Since Windows 2012 R2 is based on Windows 8.1 it shouldn't have a problem.  If you enable the RAID configuration you will have to provide a driver for that capability.  Edit your question so enough information is provided an answer can be submitted.

Comment: @Ramhound I've specified the SSD M.2 disk type I want to buy

Comment: BTW, will this older OS (Windows Server 2012 R2) actually support such a new XEON?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be supported?  Windows Server 2012 R2 is based on Windows 8.1.  The Xeon would not support Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Server 2012R2 on an NVMe PCIe M.2 drive. Done it several times.

Comment: OK, thanks for sharing your real experience. Let's do it then ;)